# Disable iMac internal display without 3rd party software

Tags: display, imac, screen

I'd like to disable my iMac's internal monitor, and just use my external monitor instead.

These are things I've tried/considered and didn't work:

#### Software Solutions

- Set brightness to "0" - That doesn't turn it off, it just dims it
- ScreenResX - I don't feel comfortable installing closed-source software from random people. It also costs a lot for what I'd use it for, and is overkill.
- Brightness Slider - It doesn't work with multiple monitors
- DisableMonitor - Apparently is damages hardware? Also old/unmaintained.

#### Other

- Buy a Mac Mini - They're not powerful enough
- Buy a Mac Pro - They're too expensive
- Use both monitors - That hurts my neck
- Leave it dim and pretend it's not there - If they're mirrored, the movement is distracting. If they're not, apps sometimes open on it or my mouse moves onto it (even if the arrangement is to only have corners touching).
- Put iMac under desk / on floor / turn it around / etc - That wouldn't work with my desk setup
- Cover it with dark fabric - This is such a simple request, it should be possible with software.

Comment: Do you, by chance mean SwitchResX? If so I have heard about it for *years.* It is from an established, professional shareware developer. So if it does what you need it to do, it is reliable and well supported and worth downloading for a free trial, at the very least.

Comment: Er, yeah. I've seen it around too, but it's still a fairly small user base, and closed source. I did end up trying it out, and it partially worked, but then prevented me from unlocking the machine after it went to sleep. The FAQ makes it sound like there's been other bugs w/ the feature lately too.